# Share variables between elements in polymer

Tags: polymer

I have a component `<my-comp>` which has a property with double binding which I pass to a different component `<my-sec-comp show-drawer="{{showDrawer}}">`. 
When I change the property showDrawer in the parent element it is also noticed in the child element. But not the other way around. How can I achieve this?

declaration in  child element is:

```
 showDrawer : {
                type: Boolean,
                notify: true
            }
```

declaration in parent element is:

```
showDrawer : {
                type: Boolean,
                notify: true,
                observer: '_drawerChanged'
            },
```

Comment: The attribute name in your tag, <my-sec-comp show="{{drawerShown}}">, is show... Can you double check if it should be drawer-shown?

Comment: You at least need to show which way around the elements are nested. Also which version of polymer?

Comment: Can you try to give your boolean variable a default value, false? It may affect the behavior of notification, assuming you're using Polymer 1.x - https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configuring-boolean-properties

Comment: in Child Component you need to use this.set('showDrawer ', your_new_value) that the parent gets notified

Answer (score 1):

In Polymer before 2.0, you can't. There are no two way bindings between parent and child elements, only between properties and elements within the same element.

If you want to update variables from child to parent, use an event, like *this.fire('drawerChanged', this.showDrawer)* or try *this.parentElement.set('showDrawer', this.showDrawer)* inside your _drawerChanged method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux for this it allows you to share information between any components. They don´t even need to be siblings. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux)